# NextJS NextAuth options.providers is not iterable. Can't figure out why

Tags: typescript, mongoose, next.js, next-auth

I am working on a project that I'm building with Next.JS. I am following the article [here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/authentication-patterns-with-nextauth-and-mongodb-in-next-js-13-2c1fa98d6b5e) and the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2h54xz6Ndw). When I run `npm run dev` everything compiles and runs smoothly. As soon as I try to use the API with Thunder Client, I get the error `TypeError: options.providers is not iterable` and a 500 Internal Server Error.

I found a similar question to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73826348/typeerror-options-providers-is-not-iterable-in-next-auth) but had already implemented the solution in my code.

I looked at the NextAuth documentation and can't find any reason this won't work.

So, my code is primarily sourced through watching the video linked above, however, I did have to source some of it from the article above as well. The code below is how I have everything setup.

**route.ts | in app/api/auth/[...nextauth]**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import options from './options'

const handler = NextAuth(options)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

**options.ts | in app/api/auth/[...nextauth]**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { MongoDBAdapter } from '@next-auth/mongodb-adapter'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

import {dbConnect} from '@/lib/utils'
import clientPromise from '../../../../lib/clientPromise'
import User from '../../../models/User'

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET!,
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        GitHubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            id: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: 'Email:',
                    type: 'email',
                    placeholder: 'Your Cool Email'
                },
                password:  {
                    label: 'Password:',
                    type: 'password'
                }
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                await dbConnect()
                // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied
                if (credentials == null) return null

                // Login
                try {
                    const user = await User.findOne({email: credentials.email})

                    if (user) {
                        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
                            credentials.password,
                            user.password
                        )
                        if (isMatch) {
                            return user
                        } else {
                            throw new Error('Email or password is incorrect.')
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('User not found')
                    }
                } catch (err:any) {
                    throw new Error(err)
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
        newUser: '/dashboard',
        error: '/login'
    },
    callbacks: {
        // We can pass in additional information from the user document MongoDB returns
        async jwt({ token, user}: any) {
            if (user) {
                token.user = {
                    _id: user.id,
                    email: user.email,
                    username: user.username,
                    firstName: user.firstName,
                    lastName: user.lastName
                }
            }
            return token
        },
        // If we want to access our extra user info from sessions we have to pass it the token here to get them in sync:
        session: async ({ session, token }: any) => {
            if (token) {
                session.user = token.user
            }
            return session
        },
    },
}

export default NextAuth(options)
```

**User.ts | in models/User.ts**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        firstName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            min: 3,
            max: 15
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            min: 6,
            max: 15
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true},
)

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)
```

**clientPromise.ts | in lib/clientPromise.ts**

```
// This approach is taken from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error("Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local");
}

const uri: string = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
let client: MongoClient;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).

  let globalWithMongoClientPromise = global as typeof globalThis & {
    _mongoClientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;
  };

  if (!globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri);
    globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = globalWithMongoClientPromise._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

**utils.ts | in lib/utils.ts**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

export async function dbConnect() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI!);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Connection Failed!')
    }
}
```

What I expected from this code was that when I ran the GET request to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers in Thunder Client, I would get a Status 200 Ok and a bit of JSON about my providers information.